# How to animate dynamic scaling and z offset in Array modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers

I want to achieve an effect simmmilar to one in [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwIrto5IX-0&list=PLq8VbG4XkAtZQl6O4WJJhUZdXXm4QTgTR) video. Basically I want to animate the scale of the specific (e.g. top ones) parts of objects' "layers"  created via Array modifier as well as the z value of them, so they appear as they are not all the same distance one from another...

Comment: You can use an empty as Object Ofsset, and animate the scale of that empty over time.

Comment: I know, but that's not what I mean. This is linear. I want to be able to make it so say - top object scale faster than bottom ones, as well as they have bigger gaps between them.. see the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an empty as **Object offset** to control the array modifier will give you a lot of options.
If you play with the reltive offset you can get things like this:

[image]

Changing the distance and size of the empty you'll control the relative distance of the cloned items in the array.
[image]
You can then add keyframes:

[image]

By adding a lattice on the scene and a **lattice modifier** to the plane to the stack you can further control the deformation (as in the opening of the video used as reference on the question:

[image]

Comment: thanks! lattice should've come to my mind :P one more question though - how can I animate lattice deformation?

Comment: @selrond on the lattice you can use shapekeys